# How can I compare different columns of different rows in the same MySQL table (in php)?

Tags: php, mysql, compare, match

I'm trying to compare column A of row A to column B of row B. How could I go about doing this in php?

This is the code i have:

```
<?php

include("include/config.php");
include("include/functions/import.php");

$addToFriends = array();
$atf = 0;

//connect to mysql and get data for main user
mysql_connect($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DBNAME);

//grabs all friend requests sent by user
$sql = "SELECT * FROM friends_requests WHERE REQUESTER = '.$_SESSION[USERID].' ";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$ar1 = array();
$RIDs = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$ar1[] = $row[2];
$RIDs[] = $row[0];
echo "ar1".$ar1[$i];
$i++;
}

//grabs all friend requests sent to user
$sql = "SELECT * FROM friends_requests WHERE REQUESTEE = '.$_SESSION[USERID].' ";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


$ar2 = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$ar2[] = $row[1];
echo "ar2".$ar2[$i];

$i++;
}


    for($int = 0; $int < sizeof($ar1); $int++)
    {

        for($t = 0; $t < sizeof($ar2); $t++)
        {

            if($ar1[$int] == $ar2[$t])
            {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM friends_requests WHERE RID = '.$RIDs[$int].' ";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
            echo "lookie".$row[1];
            echo "lookie".$row[2];
            echo "/".$t;
            echo "/".$int;
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (USERID,FRIENDID,time_added) VALUES ($row[1],$row[2],NOW())");
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (USERID,FRIENDID,time_added) VALUES ($row[2],$row[1],NOW())");
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM friends_requests WHERE REQUESTER = $row[1] AND REQUESTEE = $row[2]");
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM friends_requests WHERE REQUESTER = $row[2] AND REQUESTEE = $row[1]");
                echo "make friends".$row[1]."b/w".$row[2];  }
            }

        }

    }


?>
```

the goal is to find the two rows out of as many as there are where ColumnA,RowA = ColumnB,RowB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require a self join. Assuming (from your code) that column A is requester and coumn B is requestee. See the following example to get all records from the comparison. Tweak and add more filters to the query as per your requirements.

```
select a.*,b.* from friends_requests a, friends_requests b 
where a.requester = b.requestee
```